# How to Scramble and descramble Single script Using TSDuck

Tags: iptv, ott

```
tsp -v \
  -I ip 233.1.1.1:1001 \
  -P scrambler --cw bf0fbe87fa57acc7829a1e32d0aec0b0 --aes-ctr 2001 \
  -P analyze --interval 30 -o scrambled.txt \
  -O ip 235.1.12.12:1234
```

Scramble and descramble was single script it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Script :

```
#! /bin/bash

    tsp -v \
      -I ip 233.1.1.1:1001 \
      -P scrambler --cw bf0fbe87fa57acc7829a1e32d0aec0b0 --aes-ctr 2001 \
      -P analyze --interval 30 -o scrambled.txt \
      -O ip 235.1.12.12:1234 | \
    tsp -I ip 235.1.12.12:1234 \
      -P descrambler --cw bf0fbe87fa57acc7829a1e32d0aec0b0 --aes-ctr 2001 \
      -P analyze -i 30 -o descrambled.txt \
      -O ip 235.12.1.11:1234 \
    </dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 2>file.txt & echo $! > $STREAM_PID_PATH
```